# how to list my shelved changes in perforce?

Tags: perforce

p4 shelve saved a lot of my effort to edit the same file with different changes.

The problem is after i shelved some changes, I start to forget what I've shelved. 
Is there a way to list all the changes I've shelved? 
  I checked `p4 help unshelve/shelve` but could not find the option.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This should list all the shelved changes per user.

```
p4 changes -u <USERNAME> -s shelved
```

Comment: +1 for the proposed solution. very surprising there seems to be no such feature in the P4V GUI ...

Comment: See my answer... you can use `--me`

Answer (score 14):

```
p4 changes -s shelved
```

My colleague find the answer for me, and I answer my own question here.

Comment: This shows all shelved changelists. Your question, which is the more reasonable question in a nontrivial environment, is how to find _your_ shelved changelists. @Tuxdude provided a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of `p4`, you don't have to type out your username:

```
p4 changes --me -s shelved
```