# How to revert open files in workspace WITHOUT removing them from their changelist in perforce?

Tags: perforce, revert, shelve, changelist

Is it possible in perforce (server version 2010.1/265509 (2010/09/23), so I don't have newer "git like" server functionality) to revert all the open files in a client without the files being removed from the changelist they belong to?

By default if I have a file open and in a changelist (non-default), and I want to do a quick "context switch" away from my current working state, look at something else, then return to my prior working state, I do this:

- Create a new changelist
- Add files to the new changelist C
- Shelve files in the changelist C
- Revert all open files
- Do stuff
- revert all open files
- unshelve changelist C -c C

At the in-between stage during "do stuff", p4 describe C shows no files in the changelist.   This is disturbing and annoying and makes keeping track of what's in C harder than it should be.

Is there some way to "revert all open  files" so that "p4 describe C" keeps all the files in changelist C?

Comment: Could this be interpreted as "how can I list files that are shelved"? If so, I think this one would answer it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578881/how-to-list-my-shelved-changes-in-perforce).

Comment: `p4 files @=C` will list shelved files in C.

Comment: @DaisukeShimamoto: Actually, that question describes how to list shelved changesets, not how to list shelved *files*.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Oops, sorry! You're right. I misread the linked question. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @jamesdlin - Perfect!    Submit that as an answer and I'll accept.  It's not exactly what I wanted, but it gives me the same info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to do what you're specifically asking for (although if you really wanted to, you could write a script to revert the files in a specified changeset and then to immediately reopen them).

However, if your intent is just to list the files in a shelved changeset *C*, instead of using `p4 describe C`, you can use `p4 files @=C`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one workspace. I often have dozens of workspaces.

Comment: That's the "nuclear" option.   And this is at work, and of course our repository is ginormous, so this is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Ugh, a VCS that relies on multiple local working copies/mirrors of a remote repo in order to allow for an efficient day-to-day workflow makes me cringe. Why is this such a recurring theme with P4?